# addsuffix behaviour in tcsh complete

Tags: tcsh, tab-completion

I am working with a Makefile for conversion of documents.
To specify which document to convert, I have to give folder names in 2 make-variables:
`NAME` and `DATE`.
The directory structure is `/data/$(NAME)/$(DATE)`

`NAME` may contain numbers and characters.
`DATE` follows this format: `YYYYMMDD_XXXXXXXX` where `X` is a hex-char.
I want to make complete suggest the `NAME` and `DATE` variables in tcsh (mandatory use on site), because it is annoying to enter those random X-chars.

I ended up having the following to suggest me the `NAME` variable:

`'c@{NAME}=@D:/data@' \
'C/N*/(NAME=)/'`

This works as expected as long as I do `unset addsuffix`.
`make N[TAB] » make NAME=[TAB] » make NAME=10001.1`
If `addsuffix` is set, the cursor will be after the trailing whitespace in `make NAME=`.
For `complete` a new word starts, so it does not suggest me the directories for `NAME` then.
If I go to `NAME=` then, it also adds the trailing `/` to folder name, which is not needed.

Is there a way to disable this behaviour for these completions?
[tcsh.org](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Special_shell_variables.html#addsuffix) states:

> **addsuffix** If set, filename completion adds `/' to the end of directories and a space to the end of normal files when they are matched exactly. Set by default.

Obviously I want to keep the behaviour (as set by the user) for other completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [suffix] is what I want to be void.

from documentation:

> **complete** [command [word/pattern/list[:select]/[[suffix]/] ...]]

So I end up with

`` complete make \
'c@NAME=@D:/data/@' \
'c@DATE=@`echo $COMMAND_LINE | sed -f /data/sandbox/sbulka/tmp/sed-tmp.sed | xargs ls`@' \
'C/N*/(NAME=)//' \
'n/NAME=/(DATE=)//' ``

The sed is in a file so I don't have to bother quoting. Looks like this:

`s/^.*NAME=\([^ ]*\).*$/\/data\/\1/`